# Execute Synchronous / Blocking API calls in react

Tags: reactjs, synchronized

I'm implementing a login action which I would like to run synchronously.

My handler Function
`

```
  const handleSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      const user = await Auth.signIn(email, password); // step1 
      dispatch(login(user)); // step2
      const profile = await getMyProfile(); // step 3 
      dispatch(setTwitterProfile(profile)); // step 4
      console.log('Twitter Profile: ', twitterProfile); // step 5
      const userInfo = await Auth.currentUserInfo();
      console.log('User Info: ', userInfo);
      // navigate('/home');
    } catch (error: any) {
      dispatch(logout());
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };
```

`

The way I would like this function to execute is run second step only when step one is completed and so on.
Sometimes my pofile object is empty as results are asynchronous.

Trying : Async Await to run code imperatively
Expecting : Each step runs after result is fetched from the previous step

Comment: I think if getMyProfile relies on dispatch to complete, you can handle all the network calls first and then make the dispatch calls at the end if its possible

Comment: It didn't work but when i add a time out  of 2 seconds between step 3 and step 4
It works fine

Comment: You  can try putting `Promise.resolve(dispatch(setTwitterProfile(profile))` before checking for updates, as React batches state udpates, so in a event handler the updated state wont be reflected immediately unless an await is encountered